# Different behaviors when instantiated from button or timer in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, concurrency, timer

I have a function called `getMessages` that can be called by a Button click (using the RelayCommand trigger) or that is called in a timer every 15s.

The desired behavior is:

> webservice > deserialize answer > system notification > updatelistview > insert localDB

But when the function is called by the timer the `updatelistview` is not done. Why does this happen if the function is the same and works perfectly in the button command?

CODE:

```
 // Get messages for the logged in user
    public async void getMessages()
    {
        try
        {
            List<FriendGetMessage> msg = new List<FriendGetMessage>();
            var response = await CommunicationWebServices.GetCHAT("users/" + au.idUser + "/get", au.token);
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) // If there are messages for me.
            {
                var aux = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                IEnumerable<FriendGetMessage> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<FriendGetMessage>>(aux);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    foreach (var m in result)
                    {
                        msg.Add(m);
                    }
                    //MsgList=msg;
                    foreach (var f in Friends)
                    {
                        if (f.msg == null || f.msg.Count() == 0)
                        {
                            f.msg = new ObservableCollection<Messages>();
                        }
                        foreach (var mess in msg)
                        {
                            if (mess.idUser == f.idUser)
                            {
                                Messages mm = new Messages();
                                mm.received = mess.message;
                                mm.timestamp = "Received " + mess.serverTimestamp;
                                mm.align = "Right";
                                // Add to the friend list.
                                f.msg.Add(mm);
                                // Add to Local DB
                                InsertMessage(null, au.idUser.ToString(), f.idUser, mess.message, mess.serverTimestamp);

                                var notification = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon()
                                {
                                    Visible = true,
                                    Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information,
                                    BalloonTipIcon = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info,
                                    BalloonTipTitle = "New Message from " + f.name,
                                    BalloonTipText = "Message: " + mess.message,
                                };
                                // Display for 5 seconds.
                                notification.ShowBalloonTip(5);

                                // The notification should be disposed when you don't need it anymore,
                                // but doing so will immediately close the balloon if it's visible.
                                notification.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    counterChat = 1; // resets the counter  
                }
            }
            else {
                counterChat = counterChat * 2;
            }
            //var sql = "select * from chat";
            //var respo = GetFromDatabase(sql);
            OnPropertyChanged("Friends");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("GetMessages: " + e);
            Debug.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
    }
```

CODE TIMER:

```
public void chatUpdate()
    {
        _timerChat = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
        _timerChat.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        _timerChat.Tick += new EventHandler(timerchat_Tick);
        _timerChat.Start();
    }
    public void timerchat_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counterChat != incChat)
        {
            incChat++;
        }
        else
        {
            getMessages();
            OnPropertyChanged("Friends");
            incChat = 0;
        }
    }
```

ADDED - I've also tried this and didn't worked (it seems that is some kind of concurrency problem to the ObservableCollection called Friends (is a friendslist) each friend has an ObservableCollection of messages (is a chat))

```
public void chatUpdate()
    {
        _timerChat = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
        _timerChat.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        _timerChat.Tick += new EventHandler(timerchat_Tick);
        _timerChat.Start();
    }
    public async void timerchat_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (counterChat != incChat)
        {
            incChat++;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)async delegate { await getMessages(); });
            incChat = 0;
        }
    }
```

Best regards,

Comment: It sounds like you're not updating the UI on the UI thread. Can you post your code so we can check.

Comment: Because you call it not from UI thread

Comment: `Code` speak louder than text

Comment: @ChrisF already edited the code.

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev  but I'm using the OnPropertyChanged (you can check the code in the post), thanks :)

Comment: Calling OnPropertyChanged from bad thread does nothing. Try to call something like Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=>OnPropertyChanged("Friends")); or Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=>getMessages());

Comment: @LeonidMalyshev I've tried your suggestions in the Timer but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make the timer handler be an async method as follows:

```
public async void timerchat_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (counterChat != incChat)
    {
        incChat++;
    }
    else
    {
        await getMessages();
        OnPropertyChanged("Friends");
        incChat = 0;
    }
}
```

This way OnPropertyChanged("Friends") is guaranteed to fire after the work in getMessages is done.

The methods need to change to:

```
  DispatcherTimer _timerChat = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
        _timerChat.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        _timerChat.Tick += new EventHandler(timerchat_Tick);
        _timerChat.Start();


    public async void timerchat_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
//...
        await getMessages();
//...
    }

    public async Task getMessages()
    {
        try
        {
            // ... your code here
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // .... rest of your code
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("GetMessages: " + e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: My method (getMessages) is void and if I put task and return Task gives an error

Comment: Try returning Task<string> from getMessage, I think

Comment: But I don't have any task in the function, I do some webservices requests (you can see above)

Comment: You don't have to explicitly return a task in getMessages, just change the return type to task, the compiler will do the rest for you

Comment: I don't have the content to readAsString and if I keep the way I have it says that I don't return the correct type...

Comment: remove the "var aux = " since it's not even used and return Task ? does that not work? can you paste the code that it's not working

Comment: I've used this also in the timer: Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)async delegate { await getMessages(); });  and didn't updated the UI also.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. The problem was in my ViewModels I was opening multiple threads and sometimes the right one would update the UI and sometimes no.

Thanks for all the answers.